# Getting Bitmap from WebView generates OutOfMemory crash

Tags: android, webview, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a custom `WebView` and I want to get a bitmap of its content (offscreen included). I used this code, which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942623/which-can-replace-capturepicture-function/20963109#20963109):

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromWebviewV2(WebView webView) {
    webView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
        View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(),
            webView.getMeasuredHeight());
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getMeasuredWidth(),
            webView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bm);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int iHeight = bm.getHeight();
    bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, iHeight, paint);
    webView.draw(bigcanvas);
    return bm;
}
```

It works fine up to the point when I zoom in a lot, in which case I get OutOfMemory Crash. I tested this with the same picture (slightly zoomed and zoomed to the max) and it behaves in the same way I mentioned above.

I tried to counter this by adding

```
while(webView.canZoomOut()){
      webView.zoomOut();
}
```

at the start, but it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Quick workaround - You can add android:largeHeap="true" in manifest file for more memory.

Comment: nasty workaround which won't work most of the times.... it will just delay your OOM exception

Comment: for me it is obvious that you wan to get too large bitmap. You can't get infinite memory in your app.

Comment: The problem is that I can't reduce bitmap size after zooming in. When I use the function with initial scale it works just fine... And I already got the largeHeap on.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've cracked this one meself. The problem indeed was in the fact that the function returned the `Bitmap` waay before the zooming out procedure was over, so I had to delay it.

I incorporated

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //bulk of my code
            }
        }, 1000);
```

which forced to change the structure of the function from `public Bitmap` to `public void`. [Here's directly related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45642180/android-getting-public-bitmap-function-return-before-delay-ended/45642323?noredirect=1#comment78244732_45642323). Despite some minor tweaks I still need to fix, the approach works like a charm

Comment: So, why don't you directly get the original dimensions of your `WebView` before it's zoomed in and use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`, using the original dimensions as target dimensions for the `Bitmap`?

Comment: @Oleksandr Firsov , are you sure you did not get any out of memory by using handler.

Comment: @Chestan Joshi Nope, tested it quite a few times with different images and no errors.

Answer (score -1):

Quick fix:-

Set **android:largeHeap="true"** in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<application
    android:name="yourapplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_rounded"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_rounded"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Gud luck :)

Comment: This flag is often ignored and even in case of large heap, you still have a possibility to get OOM when creating a bitmap.