# How to print whole WebView(Scrollable)?

Tags: android, printing, webview

I want to print the whole `WebView` on Button Click.

I used Citizen Printer. 
I tried Below way.

```
private Bitmap CitizenWebPrint(WebView webView) {
    Bitmap bitmapCitizen = null;
    Picture capturePicture = webView.capturePicture();
    int width = capturePicture.getWidth();
    int height = capturePicture.getHeight();

    try {
        bitmapCitizen = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    capturePicture.draw(new Canvas(bitmapCitizen));

    return bitmapCitizen;
}
```

But Problem is,
**This can print only visible part of `WebView`.**

> How can I print the whole WebView?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which can replace capturePicture function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942623/which-can-replace-capturepicture-function)

Comment: @godslayer_69 I tried That Answer but did not get success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the DecorView object of the current window, and then draw the Bitmap object.

And you can do like this.

Before doing it ,you can do this.

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true); 
    webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("your url");
```

And check version.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    checkSdkVersion();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_capture);
}

// check version
private void checkSdkVersion() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
    }
}
```

Add permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**Way 1**

```
private void getScreenshot() {
    float scale = webView.getScale();
    int webViewHeight = (int) (webView.getContentHeight() * scale + 0.5);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), webViewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    webView.draw(canvas);
    // save to the File
    try {
        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/webview_capture1.jpg";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        // Save
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(WebviewFromDraw.this, "Screenshot OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        bitmap.recycle();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

**Way 2**  use `webView.getDrawingCache();`

```
private void getScreenshot() {

    bitmap = webView.getDrawingCache();
    try {
        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/webview_capture2.jpg";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(WebviewFromDrawCache.this, "Screenshot OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //recycle
    if(bitmap!=null) {
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

**Way 3** the same to yours,it works well in my device.

```
private void getScreenshot() {
    Picture picture = webView.capturePicture();
    int width = picture.getWidth();
    int height = picture.getHeight();
    if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        picture.draw(canvas);
        try {
            String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/webview_capture3.jpg";
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(WebviewFromCapture.this, "Screenshot ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            bitmap.recycle();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now my method is also working, No need to store the file in SD card.

I just add `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
    }` in my code, and my code is working fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just give you test.And you will be easy to know it .