# Create Bitmap from WebView content in Android

Tags: android, webview, kotlin

I've tried to find a better solution for create bitmap from WebView content, but I can't find a approach. I did try following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942623/which-can-replace-capturepicture-function/20963109#20963109), and it works, however, some methods are deprecated like `webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` and `webView.buildDrawingCache()`. Is there any better solution to achieve it?

My second approach is to use `webView.draw(canvas)` like below, but it doesn't save the whole page *WebView Content*.

```
web.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
        View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
web.layout(0, 0, web.measuredWidth,
        web.measuredHeight)


val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(web.measuredWidth, web.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
web.draw(canvas)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();` before you inflate your webview to get your entire webview to draw to a bitmap. This is for SDK version >= 21.